# Pick file from storage

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to get file from file manager in android. In fact, i have this code, that open file manager:

```
 Intent getCsv = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 getCsv.setType("*/*");
 startActivityForResult(getCsv, 1);
```

But i don't know, how can i get the file to variable File file for example.
I can get a uri, but this uri have a very strange path.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri uriObj = data.getData();
        }
    }
```

For example, path of uri: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Atests.csv`.
How can i get a File?

I have tried this:

```
Uri uriObj = data.getData();
File fff = new File(uriObj.getPath());
```

But file is `"/document/primary:tests.csv"`. The true file: `/storage/emulated/0/tests.csv`